# How do you only update NuGet packages with certain IDs?

Tags: nuget

According to the [NuGet documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Update_Command):

> Update Command
>
> Update packages to latest available versions. This
>   command also updates NuGet.exe itself.
>
> Usage `nuget update <packages.config|solution>`
>
> Options:
>
> Id - Package ids to update.

This says that the ID option is the package ID**s** to update. How do you provide multiple ID's?

This works:

```
NuGet.exe update "MySln.sln" -RepositoryPath "MyRepoPath" -id Ref1
```

...but how do you also udpate Ref2? This fails:

```
NuGet.exe update "MySln.sln" -RepositoryPath "MyRepoPath" -id Ref1,Ref2
```

I am trying to update a subset of packages and prevent the need for a large number of calls to NuGet.exe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify the `-id` option several times:

```
NuGet.exe update "MySln.sln" -RepositoryPath "MyRepoPath" -id Ref1 -id Ref2
```

Comment: It seems to me that this only works if all the projects in the solution include both Ref1 and Ref2. Is there a way to allow for the fact that some projects do not?

Comment: @Kias_Mellbourn Nuget.exe update should only update packages that are in a project's packages.config folder - it shouldn't install packages that aren't there. It may throw up warnings on the command line but should still work.

Comment: If project has Ref1 but not Ref2, the warning will be about Ref2 and then no update will be applied for Ref1.

Comment: I tried this and specified about 7 Ids, but it didn't work. It only picked up the first two and ignored the rest.