# How to update multiple packages to a desired version in single nuget cli command?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-cli, nuget-console

From [Nuget CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference) is it possible from a single command to upgrade multiple packages to the desired version?

I know we can do

```
nuget.exe update "FooBar.sln" MyPackage -Version 1.0
```

but what if I want to update 2 packages to `1.0`?

This still updates to the latest version but not to the version I desire.

```
nuget.exe update "FooBar.sln" -Id MyPackage -Id MyPackage2 -Version 1.0
```

What will be the command for that and will there be any dependency on each other like both package will update only when they both are on a project (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16302774/1011959)?

Comment: Can I know the reason why you want update multiple packages to a desired version in single nuget cli command? You can just update those packages with two nuget cli commands.

Comment: @Alex: I need to update couple of packages in a solution. One way is to do it one by one. Other way I was expecting was to send the instructions in a single command. I know this can happen in Visual Studio Nuget Package Console but was thinking if this can be done from nuget cli.

Comment: This seems to be the best documentation I could find. It shows among others how to update all packages in one solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages

Alternatively, I think Paket may offer what you need: https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/

Comment: FYI - `nuget.exe` CLI has been superseded by [`dotnet` CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x).

Comment: @NightOwl888: Yes, but there's no command to `update-package` as of today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to specify package version only when you update one package.
If you want to do it with NuGet Cli and in one command, you can join several commands like that

```
nuget.exe update "FooBar.sln" MyPackage -Version 1.0 && nuget.exe update "FooBar.sln" MyPackage2 -Version 2.0
```

With this approach you can specify different versions for different packages.